# map <img src={}> does not render my images

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to make my react sample codes.

it should be worked in my theoretical way.

1. get image data by executing Axios.
2. after receiving data check the data length
3. if the data length is not 0 then, render all images

but my  prints nothing after receiving the image data.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Loader from './components/Loader';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
const Main = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    async function get() {
      try { 
        const result = await axios.get("some URL address to get some image"     
        );
        setData(result.data);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("error:", e);
      }
    }

    get();
  }, []);

  console.log("The data: ", data);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%", marginTop: "40vh", textAlign: "center" }}>
      { data.length !== 0 ? (
         ///data contains 4 images such as data[0].img_url "https://dl.dropbox..." data[1].img_url:"https://dl.dropbox..."
         // and so on
         //but map function below does not render any image.
        data.map(array => {
          <img src= {array.img_url} />
        })

      ) :(
        console.log("There is no data")
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

please help me to render my codes properly

Answer (score 0):

Your map function needs to *return* the img tags:

```
data.map(array => {
  return <img src= {array.img_url} />
})
```

or lose the curly braces for an implicit return:

```
data.map(array => <img src= {array.img_url} />)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the **return** statement. Every map should return a JSX element inside a body.